# Error adding from database to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a panel that is visible only when the Edit button from `GridView` is clicked.

In that panel is a form with a `DropDownList` and a `TextBox` where you can write a number and add it to a `ListBox`.

After all the numbers wanted are added to the `ListBox` when I click the button Finalize is adding to the database the data. In `Gridview` I have the name concatenate from database , because I have Lastname and Firstname separately.

To be more easy I chose to add from database in `DropDownList` when I click on Edit button with the specific ID.

When Edit button is clicked this error is showing:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

In the line where I add in `DropDownList`. I verified the names of my database, of my table , all and is correct. I even tried only with firstname , not concatenate and it does the same error. I don't know what is wrong. I hope you can help me. This is the code where the error appears.

```
protected void btnEditSO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panelSO.Visible = true;
    btnFinalizeSO.Text = " Update ";

    Button but = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow grid = (GridViewRow)but.NamingContainer;

    string select_sql_SOddl = "SELECT ID, (LASTNAMER | | ' ' | | FIRSTNAMER ) AS REFERENTNAME FROM REFERENT_SHIPPING WHERE ID=" + grid.Cells[14].Text;

    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ToString()))
    {
        con.Open();

        OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand(select_sql_SOddl, con);

        OracleDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            ddlReferentShip.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
         // ddlReferentShip.Items.Add(dr["REFERENTNAME"].ToString());
         //   ddlReferentShip.DataSource = dr1;
        //    ddlReferentShip.DataTextField = dr1["REFERENTNAME"].ToString();
        //    ddlReferentShip.DataValueField = dr1["ID"].ToString();               
        //    ddlReferentShip.DataBind();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: what is select_sql_SO?

Comment: I tried with every method I know. The comment lines I tried that too , and do not work

Comment: is something that I have in my code but I deleted that , and I forgot to delete that sql when I posted here. sorry

Comment: check your where condition. I think your query is not returning any row.

Comment: Do one thing remove your where condition and extra code cmd1, dr1. make on query and one datareader and try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking `dr1.Read()`

and reading `dr[0].Tostring()`

Also try to clear the list before adding the data. Then the index should be 1 if you need to show the name

it should be

```
 while (dr1.Read())
        {
            ddlReferentShip.Items.Add(dr1[1].ToString());

        }
```

I guess ID is numeric in query you are passing as `.Text`

try this

```
string select_sql_SOddl = "SELECT ID, (LASTNAMER | | ' ' | | FIRSTNAMER ) AS REFERENTNAME 
FROM REFERENT_SHIPPING WHERE ID=" + Convert.ToInt32(grid.Cells[14].Text);
```

also all ways try to use parameterized query to avoide [SQL INJECTION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: yes that was , but does not work. It does not show the error , but in the dropdown is not showing anything. It shows my default value Select

Comment: @Ralucaionescu can u tell what u need to show in it..i didnt understand fully sorry

Comment: @Ralucaionescu i hope ID is integer and in query you are checking as .Text of the grid value try to convert that to int and put it in query..also try to use parameterized query

Comment: I have the GridView and when I click Edit -> In my dropdownlist to add the Referent Name concatenated with last name and first name with the ID of that row. I don't know to add exactly from GridView and I chose to add directly from database with the ID = with the column cu ID-ul specific randului

Comment: yes, now I tried. sorry for my late answer. I does not work. It still does not show anything. I tried with datatextfield and datavaluefield  and it says to me "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Boia C.'."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82905/discussion-between-sachu-and-raluca-ionescu).

Answer (score 0):

Why you set ddl item from `dr` when you have `dr1` as datareader.

Maybe you can try this:

```
protected void btnEditSO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panelSO.Visible = true;
    btnFinalizeSO.Text = " Update ";

    Button but = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow grid = (GridViewRow)but.NamingContainer;

    string select_sql_SOddl = "SELECT ID, (LASTNAMER | | ' ' | | FIRSTNAMER ) AS REFERENTNAME FROM REFERENT_SHIPPING WHERE ID=" + grid.Cells[14].Text;


    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ToString()))
    {
        con.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(select_sql_SO, con);
        OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand(select_sql_SOddl, con);
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        OracleDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        int i=0;
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            ddlReferentShip.Items.Add(dr1[1].ToString());
            i++;
         // ddlReferentShip.Items.Add(dr["REFERENTNAME"].ToString());
         //   ddlReferentShip.DataSource = dr1;
        //    ddlReferentShip.DataTextField = dr1["REFERENTNAME"].ToString();
        //    ddlReferentShip.DataValueField = dr1["ID"].ToString();               
        //    ddlReferentShip.DataBind();
        }

    }

}
```